# Struts-jquery dialog confirm + link id

Tags: jquery, struts2, modal-dialog, confirmation

I am using struts2-jquery and I am trying to create a modal dialog box for confirmation purposes to delete something.  I don't know how to pass the id or upon 'OK' to complete the action.

Below is my code to create the dialog based on struts2-jquery:

```
<sj:dialog
    id="anchordialogconfirm"
    buttons="{
            'OK':function() {               
                //id of link is needed to c
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Cancel':function() {  $(this).dialog('close'); }
            }"
    resizable="false"
    autoOpen="false"
    modal="true"
    title="Remove?"
>
 Are you sure you want to remove it?
</sj:dialog>

<sj:a openDialog="anchordialogconfirm" id="71" cssClass="deleteemp">Delete</sj:a>
```

Obviously if I put the href='' into the anchor then the dialog opens to that link rather than getting a modal confirmation dialog.

How can I retrieve the id of the anchor?  I want the id of the link for delete or at least suppress the link from being engaged until it is 'OK' to do so.

Comment: I'd suggest you to throw away SJ and just use plain jQuery. Sure, it's not java-ish to write actual code (even though it'd be just a single HTML tag and two JS function calls) - but anyone familiar with jQuery will then be able to work with your code and if you ever need to debug things you won't have to deal with the code generated by JS.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an auxiliar variable to hold the data sent to the dialog.

In the link you'd put something like this:

```
<sj:a openDialog="anchordialogconfirm" onclick="aux=%{#attr.obj.id};" href="#">Remove<sj:a>
```

And you' wait for that value in your dialog:

```
<sj:dialog
            id="anchordialogconfirm"
            buttons="{
            'OK':function() {
            $('#main').load('yourUrl.action?id='+aux);
            $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Cancel':function() {  $(this).dialog('close'); }
            }"
            resizable="false"
            autoOpen="false"
            modal="true"
            title="Remove?"/>
```